# JQuery events don't work with ASP.NET MVC Partial Views

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, events

I am trying to get JQuery events to work with partial views in ASP.NET MVC. However, after you load a partial view through Ajax, JQuery seems not able to fire events for any of the elements in the partial view. I suspect that this issue will also happen if you are using other frameworks or JavaScript libraries to load partial html code with Ajax.

For instance, consider the following example:

Controller:

```
 public class TestController : Controller
    {

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult LoadPartialView()
    {
        return View("PartialView");
    }
}
```

Index.aspx

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
             $("#button").click(function() {
                 alert('button clicked');
             });
         });   
     </script>    

     <div>
     <%using(Ajax.BeginForm("LoadPartialView", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="PartialView"})){ %>
        Click <input type="submit" value="here" /> to load partial view.
     <% } %>
     </div>
     <br /><br />
     <% Html.RenderPartial("PartialView"); %>
```

PartialView.ascx

```
<div id="PartialView">
   Click <input type="button" id="button" value="here"></input> to display a javascript message.
</div>
```

Once the page loads for the first time, you can click on the "Click here to display a Javascript message" and you will get a Javascript alert message that says "button clicked". However, once you click on the "Click here to load partial view", clicking on the button that is supposed to bring the Javascript alert message doesn't have any effect.
It seems that the 'click' event is not being fired anymore.

Does anyone know why this issue occurs with JQuery and how to fix? This issue also occurs with other JQuery plugins that use events.

Answer (score 54):

I have found a solution :

Juste try to make :

```
$(document).on("click", "YOUR_SELECTOR", function(e){
  /// Do some stuff ...
});
```

Instead of :

```
$("YOUR_SELECTOR").on("click", function(e){
  /// Do some stuff ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This worked for me and is a very simple solution. However, I'm not knowledgeable enough to know the pros and cons between this and the .live() method.

Comment: @Trunker .live() is obsolete "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."

Comment: @PEOudin thanks for your answer, it did work for me! Strangely this problem only occurred in MVC 5 (after refactoring a MVC 3 application to MVC 5). For MVC 3 the "$("YOUR_SELECTOR").on(..." version did work without any problems. Maybe someone has an explanation for that?

Comment: @PeOudin excellent answer it worked finally for me I've been like two hours looking for an answer!

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595039/can-i-use-jquery-document-oneach-showcomments-functione) is similar **solution if you have partial view which loads dynamic content** after page load. Hope helps someone.

Comment: I wonder why this works and the other does not on partial view? I am looking forward for an explanation. Thanks!

Comment: This still works great today!  The only thing I would add is that it may be valuable to add an ".off"  before the ".on" binding so that you don't get duplicate event bindings:

`$(document).off('click').on('click', 'YOUR_SELECTOR', function(e) { 
    // Do some stuff... 
});`

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to handle this would be to utilize the live() method:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
         $(document).ready(function() { 
             $("#button").live('click', function() { 
                 alert('button clicked'); 
             }); 
         });    
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome. This does indeed work. According to the official documentation live() can be used to attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now or in the future.

The only drawback is that the other people who wrote the plug-ins didn't apparently use the live method. Hence, to make it work with existing plug-ins, someone would probably need to dig in the source code and tweak it.

Comment: True.  That or after the content is added to the page, you could call the plugin again instead of just on page load.  If the answer suffices, please mark it as accepted...

Comment: This answer is outdated, see answer from PEOudin.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("input[id^=button]").live('click', function() { 
               //Your Code     

    }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What also works for me is to put the jquery stuff in the partial view. Just make sure only controls in the loaded view are referenced, otherwise you may get a handler that is registered twice for a control.

PartialView.ascx:

```
<div id="PartialView">
   Click <input type="button" id="button" value="here"></input> to display a javascript message.
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#PartialView").find("#button").click(function() {
             alert('button clicked');
         });
     });   
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of These solution worked for me, so i had to do these things to work:

1. I created a partial view and put all my JavaScript references in that file
2. I created a div like this

```html
<div id="js">
       @Html.Partial("[Your_Path]")
</div>
```

3.When i load some partial page after that i do this in JavaScript:

```
$('#js').load('/Your_Controller/Your_Partial_function');
```