# Can I use jQuery $(document).on('each', '.showComments', function(e) {})

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery UI dialog to show comments or other text depending upon what is clicked.

Here is my JSfiddle link [Dialog Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brijesh26/6wMRe/3/)

I have used the code

```
$('.showComments').each(function () {
    var panel = $(this).parent().siblings('.divCommentDetail');
    $(this).click(function () {
        panel.dialog('open');
    });
});

$('.showContractChanges').each(function () {
    var panel = $(this).parent().siblings('.divContractChangeDetail');
    $(this).click(function () {
        panel.dialog('open');
    });
});


$(".divCommentDetail, .divContractChangeDetail").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    open: function () {
        $(this).parent().siblings('.ui-dialog-titlebar').addClass('ui-state-error');
    },
    show: {
        effect: 'blind',
        duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
        effect: 'explode',
        duration: 1000
    }
});
```

and the content is added dynamically on page load. I am trying to use $(document).on('each', '.showComments', function(e) {}); so that it can work with dynamically loaded content, but it doesn't work at all. here is my modified code.

```
$(document).on('each', '.showComments', function () {
    var panel = $(this).parent().siblings('.divCommentDetail');
    $(this).click(function () {
        panel.dialog('open');
    });
});
```

but this doesn't work at all. Am i doing something wrong.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "each" is not an event that gets fired, it is simply a loop.  Was there something not working with your code before the change?

Comment: Hi nzifnab, when the page is loaded first time everything works fine, but my page can add more content and its using ajax to refresh, once i add new stuff the above code stops working. i see the dialog div tag content on my page, but not the dialog box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `.divContentDetail` is added dynamically after page load, it's not the loop you need to change, but the event that you are registering:

```
$(document).on('click', '.showComments', function () {
  var panel = $(this).parent().siblings('.divCommentDetail');
  panel.dialog('open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.on` bind event that work on dynamicly added elements. But `'each'` is not an event, it's a method.

You should use on like that :

```
$(document).on('click', '.showComments', function () {
    var panel = $(this).parent().siblings('.divCommentDetail');


    panel.dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: Hi Karl, thanks for the reply, i tried your suggested code but it's not working.